# What's the easiest way to do vector/matrix math in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

I want to do some simple linear algebra in an iOS app.  I need to multiply a couple 4x4 matrices, and then multiply it with a vec4.

I see there is `CATransform3D` which appears to implement some basic matrix multiplication features, but I can't seem to find anything about vector multiplications in core animation.

Is there a way to accomplish this with `CATransform3D`, or else is there another Linear Algebra library that comes as part of the iOS SDK?

Comment: How about the [simd](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/simd) API?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/working_with_matrices

Comment: I would say there is no easy way xD

Comment: Feel free to use my LA library for swift - https://github.com/AlexanderTar/LASwift